# How would you interpret this Compiler/Grammar homework question?

Tags: compiler-construction, computer-science

I'm working on my compiler homework and I have the following question:

Consider the following grammar:

> lexp -> **number** : (op lexp-seq)
>   op -> + | - | *
>   lexp-seq -> lexp-seq lexp | lexp

This grammar can be thought of as representing simple integer arithmetic expressions in LISP=like prefix form.  For example the expression 34-3*42 would be written (- 34 (* 3 42)).

*What interpretation should be given to the legal expressions (- 2 3 4) and (- 2)? What about the expression (+ 2) and (* 2)?*

---

Now, I'm not really sure what they mean by "What should the intrepretation be".  For example, do they want a derivation?

The first one seems like it would be simple enough:
(- 2 3 4)
(- 1 4)
(- 3)

And the unary (- 2) and (+ 2) I suppose would be interpreted as negative and explicit positive?

I have no clue what (* 2) would be interpreted as?

The derivation works and is easy enough:

> lexp -> (op lexp-seq)
>        -> (* lexp-seq)
>        -> (* lexp)
>        -> (* number)

But is this all they are asking for?  Or is it asking how I would interpret what (* 2) means semantically?

Please help me decipher my ambiguous homework problem!

Comment: At least your honest about it being a homework problem.

Comment: I would ask for clarification to a course coordinator/TA/whatever your school calls the prof's helpers. They will know what they want more than we will.

Comment: Agreeing with Ben S.  I interpreted the question posed the same way you did, but my opinion doesn't really matter, you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scheme (I think in lisp too) language (* ....) means "multiply all expressions in braces" so (* 2) means simply 2
And (- 2 3 4) means "2 - 3 - 4" which is -5